# Sort List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, keyvaluepair

I'm developing a program that is reading csv-files and sort them values into a KeyValuePair-List.

```
private List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> SortValues(string[,] csvData)
    {
        var dateList = new List<String>();
        var valuesList = new List<double>();

        List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();

        for (int i = 1; i < csvData.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
        {
            String date = csvData[i, 1];
            String values = csvData[i, 14];

            date = date.Remove(0, 1);
            date = date.Remove(date.Length - 1, 1);

            values = values.Remove(0, 1);
            values = values.Remove(values.Length - 1, 1);

            dateList.Add(date);
            valuesList.Add(Double.Parse(values));

            valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Double>(date, Double.Parse(values)));

        }

        var result = valueList
            .GroupBy(r => r.Key)
            .Select(r => new KeyValuePair<string, double>(r.Key, r.Sum(p => p.Value)))
            .ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

My result is a big list of dates as string and currency values as double, like this:

```
{[29.03.19, EUR]}{[28.03.19, EUR]}{[27.03.19, EUR]}{[26.03.19, EUR]}{[25.03.19, EUR]}{[19.03.19, EUR]}{[18.03.19, EUR]}{[14.03.19, EUR]}{[12.03.19, EUR]}{[11.03.19, EUR]}{[08.03.19, EUR]}{[07.03.19, EUR]}{[06.03.19, EUR]}{[05.03.19, EUR]}{[04.03.19, EUR]}{[01.03.19, EUR]}{[28.02.19, EUR]}{[27.02.19, EUR]}{[26.02.19, EUR]}{[19.02.19, EUR]}{[12.02.19, EUR]}{[11.02.19, EUR]}{[07.02.19, EUR]}{[05.02.19, EUR]}{[04.02.19, EUR]}{[01.02.19, EUR]}
```

My problem is to split these KeyValuePair-List into seperate lists for every month.

For example: I want to extract only all "KeyValuePairs" for the second month and write them into a seperate KeyValuePair-List.

Comment: I recommend using value-tuples instead of `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: I need "KeyValuePair-List" because this is my needed format, to put it into a graph

Comment: @Dai Can you go into a little more detail about how that additional learning curve would simplify OP's problem?

Comment: `.GroupBy(r => r.Key.Substring(r.Key.IndexOf(".") + 1))` will group by the string formed from the `Key` after the first `'.'` character, which I believe is `Month.Year`.

Comment: I get {[03.19, EUR]} {[02.19, EUR]} 
I dont want to sum the month values, I need every values per month in a seperate list, any idea ? :)

Comment: What is `EUR`? That's not a double...can you please provide valid sample input?

Comment: EUR are the real double values as currency like -9999,99 and + 9999,99
I dont wanted to post the real values

Comment: If you don't want the sum, then don't select `r.Sum(p => p.Value)`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a `Dictionary` where the two character string representation of the months are the `Key`:

```
SortValues(input).GroupBy(value => value.Key.Substring(3, 2)).ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToArray());
```

Feel free to parse the months in a little more elegant way, I figured that part was beside the point of what you're looking for.

If you'd like to utilize the deferred loading of LINQ, you could replace `ToArray()` with `Select(_ => _)`. Both are just a way of getting the `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,double>>` out of the `IGrouping` object that `GroupBy` gives you.

Comment: this is what I was looking for, great thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring of the `Key` that represents the month and year (by using `Substring` and starting after the `IndexOf(".")`) to group the items by a specific month, and then select each group as a list into another list, so that you end up with a `List<List<KeyValuePair< string, double>>>`:

```
List<List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>> result = valueList
    .GroupBy(r => r.Key.Substring(r.Key.IndexOf(".") + 1))
    .Select(group => group.ToList())
    .ToList();
```